# Android: Customized SearchView Layout

Tags: android, searchview

I'm implementing a search interface following android developer [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog) with the search widget. The menu is defined in res/menu/options_menu.xml

```
<menu>
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/search_view_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
     app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

then inflated in my activity

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    MenuItem searchAction =  menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchAction.getActionView();

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(this, SearchableActivity.class)));
    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    searchView.setQueryRefinementEnabled(true);

    return true;
}
```

It works as expected but what I need now is to add a second TextView under the main one. It will be used for location selection. 
What I need is done in applications like Foursquare or Yelp (screenshots)

**Foursquare**

[image: Foursquare Search widget]

**Yelp**

[image: Yelp search widget]

If there is an open source implementation it will be very useful since I will need lot of customizations.

Comment: take a look at this https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup

Comment: Thank you. It's the same link as in my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found  a solution which I think is the less invasive and don't requiere to rewrite a new custom `SearchView` class. 
`SearchView` has a main Layout `R.layout.abc_search_view` containing all its component views . But they are all aligned horizontally. I don't wand to change the configuration in the existing layout since this has lot of impacts and can change in next versions.
So I added new `LinearLayout` as sibling of the existing. I can then add anything I want in this new Layout. It even possible to move the position of any view from the original (less impact).

```
MenuItem searchAction =  menu.findItem(R.id.search);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchAction.getActionView();
//Make sure the new layout will be added under the existing SearchView child Layout 
searchView.setOrientation(SearchView.VERTICAL);
LinearLayout locationLayout  = new LinearLayout(this);
locationLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
    (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f));

TextView searchLocationView = new TextView(this);
searchLocationView.setLayoutParams(new
    SearchView.LayoutParams(SearchView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    SearchView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f));
searchLocationView.setText("R.string.my_location");
locationLayout.addView(searchLocationView);
```

Of course you can inflate your new layout from resources. Note that it's necessary to adapt the height of the toolbar to display the layouts.

The result in the screenshot below in Layout Inspector (screenshot with LinearLayoutCompat but the result is the same with LinearLayout in the code).

[image]